# Python error with request post : 'Connection aborted, timeout('The write operation timed out')

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using requests post to send some data, now I have set the timeout value of `requests.post` to something like `60`. Other similar questions where related to specific applications so I wanted to ask it as a generic python error.

this is the error that I get:

```
failed to connect  ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))
```

I assume this is because for some reason my thread couldn't send all the data in time, but I am not sure. So I have the following questions:

1. Is this error happening because the thread couldn't send out all the data in the timeout time?
2. If so, is there anyway I can set the timeout in a way that only starts after I send out all the data out? I don't want to wait for ever for the server to respond, but obviously I want the timer to start when I send all the data out, and not at the start of function call. (and the data I send varies in size)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the [python-request library](https://pypi.org/project/requests/), you can specify the 'timeout' parameter as a tuple. The first element is the "connection timeout" and the second is the "read timeout".

```
requests.get('http://google.com', timeout=(10,200) # give it 10 seconds to connect to the server, and timeout if server does not send any data back for 200+ seconds
```

requests uses the urrlib3.util.Timeout under the hood.
[Per the urllib3 docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html), setting the read timeout to None will wait forever for the server to respond. But, I agree waiting forever is a bad idea.

How much data are you sending in your request? I read through some of the python-requests code and couldnt find an easy way to detect when the request is done sending.

As a proof of concept I wrote [this code](https://github.com/GrantGMiller/request_with_event) based on [urequests (micro requests)](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/urequests/urequests.py)

It allows you to pass a callback function to the requests.get(). This callback will be triggered after all the request data is sent, but before any data is received by the server.

```
import time

def sent_callback():
    print('The request has finished sending at', time.time())

resp = get('http://google.com', send_callback=sent_callback)
print('response received at', time.time())

print('resp.text=', resp.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of a network issue, should the project be taken to a production server with high internet speed, should fix this problem (I'm still to check with my project).

But for development you can give this a try:

```py
# ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError('The write operation timed out')): Increase chunksize
storage.blob._DEFAULT_CHUNKSIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024
storage.blob._MAX_MULTIPART_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024
```